# Plausibility of this Atmosphere on Ocean worlds

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, atmosphere

My planet is an Ocean world tidally locked to [Ultra-cool red dwarf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultra-cool_dwarf) Star. (Based on [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habitability_of_red_dwarf_systems) a planet can retrain Water in this type of stars with a mass around 0.08-0.11⊙ and avoid radiation problems to a certain extent).

Planet: Mass: 4.2 / Radius: 1.7 (Unit is Earth = 1) / Inside the habitable zone with an average temperature of 11°C.

The atmosphere is composite of N2: 72%, CO2: %23, Ar: 1.5, and other gases and a bit denser than Earth, about 1.338 kg/m^3.

What is the plausibility of such a planet? Would the carbon cycle and heat distribution to the night side work?

Comment: Is the mass of your star correct, 0.8-0.11, should that be 0.8-1.1?

Comment: Mass is in what units?  Earths?  Likewise radius?

Comment: 0.08, surely...

Comment: Edited star mass to match source:    The main problem I see is determining atmospheric density. That planet will retain most of its air, forever, so at that mass it should be a little gas giant. With enough atmosphere, heat circulation is trivial. Heat retention may be an issue, its atmosphere will want to stratify and insulate it *too* well.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. I think your question is decent, but it should be narrowed down to one question - it's about three questions right now (plausibility/heat cycle/carbon cycle). Likely to get closed.

Comment: I am planning to make the people in my story colonize this planet because it has H2O water and CO2, both of them can be used to get oxygen or for plants, although they need a bit of treatment, so I don't know exactly if this is considered world-building or not. I just added the density and the planet unit is earth=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds very believable.  N2 is a little harder for a planet to hold onto than CO2 (or even oxygen), but yours is a massive world with a deep gravity well and 45% more gravity than Earth.  There are enough open questions about flares on red dwarf stars that no one should say it can't happen.  Additionally, the high-CO2 atmosphere puts it far outside (further away than) the usual "habitable zone" (look what we can do on Earth with 0.0413% CO2 and counting).  If I had a concern it would be that the planet's internal heat might be greater than what could escape through such an atmosphere, but there should be enough arguments about low occurrence of radioactive elements (depends on local supernova or neutron star collision history) or convection in the atmosphere to keep that up in the air.  Note however that CO2 + H2O = H2CO3 (carbonic acid).  Your planet will have very roughly the acidity of a bottle of soda pop - nothing can neutralize it or the atmosphere would have precipitated as bicarbonate.  This isn't a deal breaker, but be sure not to write in anything alkaline.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I think the planet is on the edge of being a gas dwarf (I may tweak that), so what I did understand that the ocean will become a carbonic acid ocean. but will the atmosphere stay the same? and the temperature 11°C means that it's a cold planet out of the habitable zone because of the greenhouse gases? and if that was true that means the planet's early temperature is low and that would result in a gas dwarf of helium so I will change the mass. So did I get it right?

Comment: The atmosphere should stay the same, in the absence of some other reason for it to change.  You can construct the same atmosphere yourself if you blow a fairly large amount of air into a used soda bottle, then drop in a match or something to use up the oxygen.  To have temperature 11 C, the planet has to be much further out than it would be if it had Earth's atmosphere and the same temperature.  I don't think you *have* to assume that further out means gas giant - see [this article](https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/resources/1045/kepler-20-an-unusual-planetary-system/).  It's your choice. :)